# Outlook forgets active directory authentication for RSS feeds

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, active-directory, rss, windows-authentication

I am using Outlook 2010 to subscribe to some RSS feeds which require authentication using my Active Directory account.

This works fine for a day or two but then Outlook forgets the authentication details. I then have to add all the feeds again.

Is there a way to tell Outlook 2010 to just use my credentials or to persists the account details?